# transferring data over socket in C

Tags: c, arrays, sockets, udp

I have a program that transfer data over Internet sockets (UDP). so there are defined char arrays as data packets. E.g. `char packet1[] = 11` (header[2 digit]) + `192.168.100.158` (sender_IP[15 digit]) + `006` (TTL [3 digit])+... (`11192.168.100.158006...`). The receiver extracts the data according to the index of the array (e.g. 0-1 is header, 2-16 is sender_IP).

My problem is that when I define the sender_IP as [2-16] and if the IP address is shorter than 15 digit (e.g. 192.168.100.5) then the receiver extracts the data wrong. My question is that how can I make sure that sender_IP would be extracted correctly even if the IP address is 15 digit or 14 digit (without adding extra character to define the string length of sender_IP)?

I was thinking to create a struct type and define something like `

```
struct packet {
   char header[1];
   char senderIP[15]
   , TTL[2];
  };
```

. but I could not figure out what to write instead of  `buf` on this line `sendto(s, buf, BUFSIZE, 0,(struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen)`, since `buf` needs to be char as I know. I need the IP address in ASCII representation as send some data to `sender_IP` address `(inet_aton(sender_IP, &si_other.sin_addr)`.

Comment: 1) pad it with spaces. 2) nul-terminate it?

Comment: By the way, buf needn't be a char*, it could be a pointer to a struct or any other type, but you almost never want to directly send a struct over sockets due to differences and packing and endianness between platforms and compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the IP's as a 32-bit int, or pack the string with zeros so it is the proper length, e.g. 192.168.100.005.

Comment: There is still the issue of network-byte order. ascii avoids this.

Comment: True. You would want to use htonl() and ntohl() if you are going to be sending ints over sockets.

Answer (score 1):

use a limit-group-char like = "!!!" or "xxx" and detect it to know where to start detection

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to copy it to a local struct which has one more byte to make place for an extra added NUL byte.

```
struct packet *in;
struct cooked_packet {
   char header[1];
   char sender_ip[1+ sizeof in->ip];
   char ttl[2];
   } this;

this.header = in.header;
strncpy(this.ip, in->ip, sizeof in->ip);
this->ip [ sizeof this.ip -1] = 0;
memcpy(this.ttl, ip->ttl, 2);
```

UPDATE:  This is one of these rare places where strncpy() could be useful.